# How to enable iconv support in mingw's gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, character-encoding, mingw, iconv

I'm trying to use mingw's gcc with -fexec-charset option to specify some encoding different than UTF-8 and I get the following error:

```
Z:\>echo char foo[] = "\u00fc"; | g++ -S -xc++ -fexec-charset=latin1 -
cc1plus.exe: error: no iconv implementation, cannot convert from UTF-8 to latin1
```

How can I check if mingw's gcc has support for iconv and how can I enable this support in case it's turned off?

---

I found bug number [2832453](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2832453&group_id=2435&atid=102435) (filed by Alexandr Zamaraev) on mingw's bugtracker at sourceforge.net about `-finput-charset` and `-fexec-charset` options not working in 4.4.0 version of mingw (that's what I'm using). Alexandr also described this problem in [post](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/30394) to MinGW-users mailing list. The bug was filed on 2009-08-05 and nothing has happend since then. I'm not sure if I'm observing this bug (I'm not even sure if it's a bug because nobody has confirmed this) or if there's something wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on your system's `libiconv`. It's telling you it can't find it (it's not a bug)

The install guide [here](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Install_%28MinGW%29) says after installation:

> However, you still need to copy zlib1.dll, iconv.dll & libxml2.dll to .../install_dir/bin

Comment: Well, there is libiconv-2.dll file in bin folder of my MinGW's installation. By the way, I don't quite get how instructions for building some specific lib which you mentioned are related to my issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the link to instructions for installing minGW (including where to put libiconv) are related to building a specific lib?  Aside from that though ... it *should* work if it finds that library and the encoding is supported.

Comment: *All files should now be installed to ~/openbabel-2-2-x/build/install_dir. However, you still need to copy zlib1.dll, iconv.dll & libxml2.dll to .../install_dir/bin.* Doesn't this mean to copy these files to **app's** directory after building the so the app works? I think so.

Answer (score 0):

When they compile the GCC EXE, they use a configure. There is a setting about ICONV in the configure. Sometime they set the item, but sometime they forgot, at that time, you need recompile the GCC EXE by yourself.